# bash: grep exact matches based on the first column

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep

I have a .txt file like below:

```
9342432_A1 9342432 1 0 0 0
4392483_A2 4392483 2 0 0 0 
4324321_A3 4324321 1 0 0 0
9342432    9342432 2 0 0 0
```

For example, I want to generate a subset with the IDs 4324321_A3 and 9342432 (based on the first column!).
I tried the following command to find the exact matches:

```
 grep -E '4324321_A3|9342432'
```

But when I use this line, I end up with a dataset like this:

```
9342432_A1 9342432 1 0 0 0
4324321_A3 4324321 1 0 0 0
9342432    9342432 2 0 0 0
```

The problem is that the line that matches a part of the ID (9342432_A1) shouldn't be there.
Can anyone help me with this?

I would like to end up with this:

```
4324321_A3 4324321 1 0 0 0
9342432    9342432 2 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It matches

```
9342432_A1 9342432 1 0 0 0
```

because it has `9342432` in the second column.

You need to update the command to make grep check lines starting with those words, that is, use `^word`:

```
$ grep -E '^4324321_A3|^9342432' file
4324321_A3 4324321 1 0 0 0
9342432    9342432 2 0 0 0
```

To make it more accurate, you can also use `-w` that matches the full word. This way `grep -wE '^4324321_A3|^9342432' file` would not match a line like

```
4324321_A3something 4324321 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex doesn't check if the ID is at the start of the line. Simply include a `^` at the beginning of your regular expression to tell it to match only ID's at the start of the line, and then group the alternatives using `()`:

```
grep -E '^(4324321_A3|9342432)\b' <file>
```

`\b` is a boundary character which forces it to only match whole words.

Answer (score 4):

When you need matching on a specific field (or column) of your files, it could be better to use a tool like `awk` instead of `grep`. you can write something like this:

```
awk '$1 == "STRING_TO_MATCH"' txtfile.txt
```

and this could work also on a column different from the first (just use $2 for second column, $3 for the third, and so on).
awk accept regex as well as grep.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Include in your grep the `^` at the beginning and after the pattern the space .

Answer (score 1):

Add a start of line anchor at the beginning and a word boundary at the end of each pattern

```
grep -E '^4324321_A3\b|^9342432\b'
```